# List is not showing in SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, web-part, web-part-zone

I have created the SharePoint list. I have tried to add the list into page zone using PowerShell script. If I execute the script it will run without any error. But in page the list does not added. After execute more then 3 times continuously, it will get reflected in the page.

My code is :

```
        $site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($SiteUrl)
        $web=$site.OpenWeb()
        try
        {
            $page = $web.GetFile("Pages/default.aspx")    
            $page.CheckOut() 

            $webpart = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart
            $list=$web.Lists.TryGetList($listName)
            $webpart.ListId = $list.ID

            $webpartmanager =  $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($pageurl,[System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
            $webpartmanager.AddWebPart($webpart,$webpartzone,$zoneorder)

            $web.update()

            $page.CheckIn("Added ")  
            $page.Publish("Added ")  
            $web.Close()
            $web.update()
        }
        catch [Exception]
        {
           Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
        }
```

Please suggest any idea to add list into page.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested and this works, your `$web.Close()` might have something to do with the problems you're seeing.

```
$siteurl = "https://yoursite.com"
$listName = "Documents"
$pageUrl = "/pages/default.aspx"
$webpartzone = "Left"
$zoneorder = 0

try
{
    $web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $siteurl
    $page = $web.GetFile($pageUrl)    
    $page.CheckOut()

    $webpart = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart

    $list = $web.Lists.TryGetList($listName)       
    $webpart.ListId = $list.ID

    $webpartmanager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($pageurl,[System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
    $webpartmanager.AddWebPart($webpart,$webpartzone,$zoneorder)

    $page.CheckIn("")  
    $page.Publish("")
}     
catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
}
finally
{
    $web.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for `web.Update` when you add webpart

Also, I usually use the below code which is somewhat different from the one you posted.

```
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($SiteUrl)
$web=$site.OpenWeb()
try
{
    $page = $web.GetFile("Pages/default.aspx")    
    $page.CheckOut() 

    $list=$web.Lists.TryGetList($listName)

    $webPartManager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($pageUrl,  [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)

    $webpart = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart
    $webpart.Title = $list.Title
    $webpart.ListName = ($list.ID).ToString("B").ToUpper()
    $webpart.ViewGuid = ($list.DefaultView.ID).ToString("B").ToUpper()
    $webpart.ZoneID = $webpartzone
    $webpart.ChromeType = "TitleOnly"

    $webpart.TitleUrl = $list.DefaultViewUrl
    $webpart.WebId = $list.ParentWeb.ID

    $webPartManager.AddWebPart($webpart, $webpartzone, $zoneorder)

    $page.CheckIn("Checked in page")  
    $page.Publish("Published page")     


}
catch [Exception]
{
   Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
}
```